# Javascript : Access a particular element in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello,

I imported an XML document from a web page that is updated at a regular interval (so I can not change it) and I used the following code to convert the object that I can access as an array:

```js
$.ajax("js/support.csv", {
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonobject = csvjson.csv2json(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

It works well, because jsonobject contains all that is in the XML file. The problem is when I try to access a specific value, it shows undefined instead of the actual value. The variable that i'm trying to have the value is "LAT" (with quotes) and LONG (without the quotes). I believe these are the quotes that are problematic, because I managed to access the variable LONG jsonobject.rows[0].LONG but not LAT.
I tried all sorts of things such as jsonobject.rows [0] .LAT, jsonobject.rows [0]["LAT"], jsonobject.rows[0].[\ "LAT \"] and jsonobject.rows[0]['"LAT"']. the characters of exhaust does not seem to work.
See Attachment
[array variables as seen in the console in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1RNt.png)

Do you have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: `jsonobject` only exists within the `success` function, so it goes out of scope (and is thus lost) right after being created. You have to do something with it. I wouldn't suggest this for a production environment, but for debugging purposes `window. jsonobject = jsonobject` would be a start.

Comment: are you talking about xml or csv? the filename suggests it's csv. Also, like @Siguza said, mind asynchronity

Comment: It's a csv file sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonobject.rows[0]['"LAT"']` way should work. Could you be more specific about the problem?

Maybe the `rows[0]` part is where you are having trouble.

```
var a = {'LONG': 10, '"LAT"': 20}
console.log(a['"LAT"']) // Prints 20
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it should work, but it doesn't because i've already tried it before posting that. My problem is that I can't access the variable "LAT" of my array (undefined), but every other variable is accessible. Example with LONG : jsonobject.rows[0].LONG returns the actual value instead of undefined.

Comment: I just posted what I think is the definitive answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to get 'LAT' property directly. Try to go step by step.
Could you the code I provided?

```js
$.ajax("js/support.csv", {
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonobject = csvjson.csv2json(data);
                    
                    var myobject = jsonobject.row[0];
                    for each (var item in myobject) {
                       console.log("LAT",item.LAT);
                    }

console.log(sum); 

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just noticed your problem. Taking a look to your screenshot it appears that the field is followed by a blank space.

This is a tough one to follow!

```
var a = {'LONG': 10, '"LAT" ': 20} // Extra space after double quote!
console.log(a['"LAT" ']) // Prints 20
```